# Google Analytics Checkout Behaviour in Bigquery

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

does anyone know how to extract checkout behaviour from the Google Analytics export in BigQuery?

E.g. I'd like to calculate abandonment at each checkout stage. I've raked through the schema  -

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719?hl=en&ref_topic=3416089

- but it doesn't seem to have the equivalent data from GA i.e. the details within shopping stages such as

> "CHECKOUT_1_ABANDONMENT"

.

I can get each checkout step using `hits_eCommerceAction_step` but can't calculate exits here, they're always just blank when I do a count of `hits.isExit`

Answer (score 0):

`hits.isExit` refers to the last page in the session. It will not help you here, unless you want to know if any step was also the session exit.

Regarding e-commerce steps, you could define the highest step number per session as being the exit step or the last one seen - but I guess the highest makes more sense?!

Oh, and you have to translate what each step number means by yourself. It literally just tracks the number, not the meaning.

You can do it like that:

```
SELECT
  (SELECT MAX(ecommerceaction.step) FROM t.hits) AS maxStep,
  SUM(totals.visits) AS sessions
FROM  `project.dataset.ga_sessions_2018*` t
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
```

If you want the "last step in a session"-logic, you would do it like that:

```
SELECT
  (SELECT ecommerceaction.step FROM t.hits WHERE ecommerceaction.step is not null ORDER BY hitnumber DESC LIMIT 1) AS lastStep,
  SUM(totals.visits) AS sessions
FROM  `project.dataset.ga_sessions_2018*` t
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
```

I didn't check if these are translations to Google Analytics numbers but should be helpful, I hope, getting in this direction.